# Import a .py file which consists of strings

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, import

I have 2 files for my python project.
One file is the main file and the other consists only of strings I wish to use in the first main file.

The strings .py file consist of:

```
string = "hey"
string_two = "bye"
```

in the main .py file, I have tried to call this file using the import function and then print the string:

```
import strings

print string
```

I got this error from console:

```
NameError: name 'string' is not defined
```

Why is this happening? shouldn't it work because I have imported the file to the main.py file?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please read the Python tutorial before asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advise you to use a name other than 'string' as that is already the name of system library in Python. Try the following:

my_strings.py

```
string_one = "hey"
string_two = "bye"
```

main.py

```
import my_strings

print my_strings.string_one
```

If you wanted to just import specific strings, you could do this in main.py

```
from my_strings import string_one
print string_one
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

normally you would

```
import strings
print(strings.string)
```

or

```
from strings import string
print(string)
```

EDIT see comment - there are issues with this, though for some modules such as tkinter it is the [recommended way](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html). (If you are simply moving some of your code into a subsidiary file for tidiness then doing this isn't an unreasonable approach)

```
from strings import *
print(string)
```

i.e. without the .py

this is a bad name for a file and a variable though.

Comment: Hey, I actually import without using '.py' (fixed it in the question now). Moreover, the variable name is just for this example :]

Comment: Please don't recommend `import *`.